# Dyer-Lashof algebra and Steenrod algebra "duality"

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, homotopy-theory

Let $X$ be a spectrum. I've heard that the action of the Steenrod algebra on $H^*(X; \mathbb{F}_2)$ and the action of the Dyer-Lashof algebra on the homology of the associated infinite loop space, $H_*(\Omega^{\infty}X; \mathbb{F}_2)$, are "dual" in some sense.

To my knowledge, this has something to do with Koszul duality, but I've never seen this spelled out in detail. Anyone willing to enlighten me on this? Or point me toward a helpful reference?

Comment: This is something I wanted to know about too.  AFAIK, this "duality" is one of the conceptual reasons underpinning H. Miller's "A spectral sequence for the homology of an infinite delooping", in which he plays off modules over the Steenrod algebra against Dyer-Lashof algebras.  Unfortunately, there isn't an explicit statement of this in the paper.